# Laurent series of $f(z) = \frac{z - 4}{(z+1)^2(z - 2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

I want to expand function $$f(z) = \frac{z - 4}{(z+1)^2(z - 2)}$$ for $1 < |z| < 2$.

**My work so far**

By partial fraction decomposition we can get that:

$$\frac{z - 4}{(z + 1)^2(z - 2)} = \frac{-3(z - 4)}{(z + 1)^2} + \frac{\frac 1 9 (z - 4)}{z - 2}$$

Now deriving Laurent expansion for second term is not so hard:

$$\frac{1}{z - 2} = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1 - \frac z 2} = - \frac 1 2 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\frac z 2)^n = - \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{z^2}{2^{n + 1}}$$

So we have that:

$$ \frac{\frac 1 9 (z - 4)}{z - 2} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty - \frac 1 9 \cdot \frac{z^n}{2^{n + 1}}(z - 4)$$

But I'm quite struggling with expanding $\frac{1}{(z + 1)^2}$. I tried several possibilities but those all led me nowhere. Can I ask you for a hand in expanding form $\frac{1}{(z + 1)^2}$?

**EDIT**

We know that $\frac{1}{1 + z} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z^{n + 1}}$

As I understood the idea with derivative is to:

$$\frac{d(\frac{1}{1 + z})}{dz} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{d(\frac{(-1)^n}{z^{n + 1}})}{dz}$$

$$- \frac{1}{(1 + z)^2} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty - (n + 1)z^{-n-2}(-1)^n$$

$$\frac{1}{(1 + z)^2} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n + 1)z^{-(n + 2)}(-1)^n$$

Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: You can expand $\frac{1}{z+1}$ and take the derivative of the Laurent series.

Comment: You have an error in your partial fraction decomposition step. You can see the difference in this graph here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/chyrpdutt9
Remember that the decomposition should be of the form $\frac{z-4}{(z+1)^2(z-2)} = \frac{Az+B}{(z+1)^2} + \frac{C}{z-2}$ for unknown coefficients $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: After the edit, it looks right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1. Compute the Laurent expansion of $\frac1{1+z}$
2. Notice that $\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{1+z}=-\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$

Comment: I updated my question. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: It's correct, although now you have to take into account Lubin's answer and go from 
$\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$ to $\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2}$ in order to make the series converge in the region $|z|>1$. Basically you have to change $z$ to $\frac{1}{z}$ in the series and add the $\frac{1}{z^2}$ term in front.

Answer (score 1):

You want a series for $\frac1{(1+z)^2}$ that’s good outside the unit circle, don’t you? Thus a series in $1/z$. So write
$$
\frac1{(1+z)^2}=\frac1{z^2}\frac1{(1+1/z)^2}\,.
$$
If you find that confusing, expand $t^2\frac1{(1+t)^2}$ in powers of $t$, and substitute $1/z$ for $t$.